# TFS vNext build and access to User Capabilities

Tags: build, tfs-2015

We delay sign assembly in DEV and when we build release I want to sign assembly. Key is in computer where is agent and access to private key is limited to some users, agent user included. I can add MSBuild parameters but I don't want to have hardcoded path to private key in every build definition. I think that I add User Capability to agent and than in task I use this capability value. But I don't know how to access value.

Is there way to get value from User Capabilities in task?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. The capabilities are designed to map with the demands defined in build definitions and thus define the pool of agents capable to run the build.

In order not to hardcode this in every build definition, you can define a variable with this value and then generate a template from your this definition. Next time you create the build definition from that template, the variable will be preset with the correct path.

Comment: OK, than value in capability is only for reference what each capability means. But why I must set value if only capability name is compared? Or I missed somethink

Comment: When you define a demand in the build definition (General tab), you specify whether it should check the corresponding capability for existence, or for the equality to some value. In the latter case it will also compare the value in demand with the value of the corresponding capability.